# Responding to jQuery Ajax request with Python

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask

I am currently trying to implement the pre-built inline editor located here: https://github.com/wbotelhos/inplace

Unfortunately, the support documentation leaves a lot to desire and I have very little experience with Javascript, jQuery, or Ajax.

I have been able to successfully implement the HTML edits:

```
<td><div class="inplace" data-field-name="name" data-field-value="{{people['name']}}" data-url="/update/{{id}}">{{ people['name'] }}</a></td>
```

The Js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.inplace').inplace();
</script>
```

and have successfully grabbed, and printed the info sent from the Javascript.

```
@app.route('/update/<id>', methods=["POST", "PATCH"])
@login_required
def update(id):
    new_data = request.get_data(as_text=True)
    print(new_data)
    return "200"
```

The issue I am facing, is that the Js returns an `Undefined` value which is what the HTML updates to.

Ignore the return "200" - I have tired several different methods. Success = True, json values, etc and nothing seems to work.

I am sure I am missing something simple.

Comment: Where is your ajax code?

Comment: I assume inside of jQuery. Not sure to be honest! Although, it has to be there as I am getting a response on the Python side haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to print json with the field name that matches your field_name attribute which is name.

So you will need to print something like this. I don't use python, so you will need to follow actual python syntax. Where the word name is correct, but you will need to add the value that you want shown

```
print('{"name":"NEW FIELD VALUE"}')
```

Comment: So this worked! return {"name": data) in Python for anyone else looking at this. The only challenge now is that the element doesn't update with the new value automatically.